# java 8,Lambda Expressions working differently while same javassist is being used

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, javassist

I have a list of student, `List<Student>`
and I am using javassist-3.9.0.GA jar.

when i am writing `list.stream().collect(Collectos.grouping(Student::getCode))`
it is giving `Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18` exception. When I change above statement as `list.stream().collect(Collectos.grouping(p->p.getCode()))` it works.

Byte code manupulation of `p->p.getCode()` and `Student::getCode` are not same?

how above two statement is working differently while same javassist is being used?

Summary:
I have a class Like:

```
class Student{

   private String code;
   private String name;


   public String getCode(){
       return code;
   }
   public void setCode(){
       this.code=code;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name){
      this.name=name;
   }
}
```

`List<Student> studentList=getStudentList();`

Now below statement is **working fine** on  javassist-3.9.0.GA jar

```
Map<String,List<TripDetail>> tripMap=studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getCode()));
```

but with the same Jar below statement is giving `invalid constant type: 18` exception

```
Map<String,List<TripDetail>> tripMap=studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCode));
```

So as per my knowledge `p -> p.getCode()` and `Student::getCode` both are same,so either both should give that exception or both should be working.

Comment: Did you mean `groupingBy`?

Comment: Yes,sorry i did not write exact syntax,

Comment: `Collectos` -> `Collectors` and `grouping` -> `groupingBy`.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: Misha, I have updated the question.

Comment: I updated my answer since you changed the question a little.

Answer (score 2):

According to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453745/play-1-2-x-unexpectedexception-continuationenhancer-on-helpers-cheatsheethelper/22552711), Javassist 3.9 doesn't fully support the Java 8 features you're using. Upgrade Javassist, if you can. If not, you're stuck with the `p -> p.getCode()` version.

As for the difference between the two syntaxes, `p -> p.getCode()` is a lambda expression that creates a new anonymous function invoking `getCode()` on its argument. The argument type comes from the functional interface the expression is fulfilling.

Meanwhile, `Student::getCode` doesn't create a new function, it's simply a lambda expression that references the existing `getCode` method of `Student`.

Fundamentally the difference is that `p -> p.getCode()` does not belong to anybody, whereas `Student::getCode` belongs to the `Student`.

I compiled a quick example to see what effect that has on the method invocation. With the `p -> p.getCode()` version, this bytecode is produced:

```
SourceFile: "LambdaExampleAnonymous.java"
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #51 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #52 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      #55 invokestatic example/LambdaExampleAnonymous.lambda$0:(Lexample/Student;)Ljava/lang/String;
      #56 (Lexample/Student;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

With the `Student::getCode` version, you get this:

```
SourceFile: "LambdaExampleReference.java"
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #44 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #45 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      #50 invokevirtual example/Student.getCode:()Ljava/lang/String;
      #52 (Lexample/Student;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

You can see that the anonymous lambda function is invoked with `invokestatic`, while the referenced method is invoked with `invokevirtual`.